# Does GridBagLayout require placeholder panels for empty cells?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I made a simple `GridBagLayout` which adds buttons in the cells (0,0), (1,0), and (0,1).

```
JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("0,0"),c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("1,0"),c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("0,1"),c);
```

I was happy to see the resultant UI:

[image: Desired result]

I want to add a `JButton` in a cell that is not connected to the existing cells. I want it to be separated by an empty space. When I try this, the new `JButton` is lumped in next to the others. Here is the addition:

```
JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("0,0"),c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("1,0"),c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("0,1"),c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panelMain.add(new JButton("3,0"),c);
```

The output:

[image: Undesired result]

The `JButton("3,0")` is displaying at the cell (2,0). Do I need to use an empty `JPanel` as a place holder in the cell (2,0)? More importantly, why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout does not know what should be the width to be left at `2,0` unless there is a component placed in the `gridx = 2`. By the time you complete the UI, if any component gets placed, it should look fine. For e.g.:

[image]

In other case you may add empty `JPanel` with background color matching to the background color of the container.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to use an empty JPanel as a place holder in the cell (2,0)?

You can use an "insets" grid bag constraint to give space between components. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the inset constraint.

Or, if you want to have a place holder then you can use a `Box.createHorizontalStrut(...)` to easily specify the width.

> More importantly, why is this happening?

Cells don't have a size unless there is a component in the cell. Each cell is independent of one another so what size would you expect cell (2,0) to be?